# How do you output an info page to pdf?

Tags: pdf, man, info

If `man -t ls | ps2pdf - > ls.pdf` is useful for outputting the `ls` man page via `ps2pdf` to pdf, what about **info** pages?

I've tried something like the following but with no success:

```
info -o info | ps2pdf - > info.pdf
```

All this does is output a blank pdf file called info.pdf and output the body into a text file.

Comment: That's good enough for me. It appears that info2man is in the Debian repositories so if you want to formulate that as an answer with example, I'll mark as correct. I can work it out without an example, but it may help anyone who stumbles upon this question.

Comment: It's also in Fedora 17 and Ubuntu according to pkgs.org

Comment: `info -o - info | /usr/bin/groff -mandoc -Tpdf > info.pdf` except it does not handle any formatting at all... not sure if there is a way to preserve that directly with the info command

Comment: Thanks but it's the formatting I was after. I might stick with the text files for info then as, while they are not pdf, they are at least laid out correctly.

Comment: According to http://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/manual/info-stnd/info-stnd.html#Printing-Nodes you should go looking for the tex sources of those info pages...?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ah, info brings along the `texi2ps` and `texi2pdf` programs.

So if you find the info source (info.texi) you can generate beautiful (or bloated, depending on your point of view) PDF using:

```
texi2pdf info.texi
```

Comment: Thanks. Don't get me wrong, I love the terminal. I just don't enjoy reading man/info pages there.

Comment: Ok, since I didn't specifically request an example, I'm going to give you the points.

Answer (score 4):

Info is a specialized format with few formatting capabilities, it's basically man with hyperlinks. Most info files are generated from a [Texinfo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texinfo) source with the `makeinfo` command. Texinfo is designed to accommodate a wide range of outputs, both hypertext and printed, with basic or pretty formatting. Supported output formats include info, HTML, DVI, PostScript and PDF.

The PDF may already be present in the same package as the info file or in a separate package (depending on how much your distributing).

If it isn't, install a Texinfo setup and get the source of the package. You can then process the Texinfo source with `texi2pdf`, and you'll get a manual in PDF format with nicer formatting.

Comment: Thanks but if it isn't a 1 or 2-step process the advantage is lost. I was just quite impressed that a single expression could turn a man page into an attractive formatted pdf document.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with this freecode.com/projects/info2man as I don't know if you can output info directly. It's in the Debian and Ubuntu repositories, at least. Simply give your class file (.ci) extension as the argument to info2man.

Comment: AUR also has it.

Comment: Could you provide an example. I've tried info2man /path/to/info-page (as per the info2man manual page) but do I need other arguments? Where does this output to?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution that may not need the info source file to convert the info pages to pdf. However, the generated pdf format may not be beautiful as you think, but it much like the info pages.
According to the `info` man pages, here is a `-o, --output=file` option to convert the info pages to `text` files. So then you can convert the `text` file to pdf with `enscript` and `ps2pdf`.

Example: `info --subnodes -o - info | enscript -o - | ps2pdf - info.pdf`
Note: `--subnodes`: recursively output menu items.
Then it will generate the `info.pdf` in your working directory.